# how to yellow and black lines from flutter android emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

In the android emulator it appears this yellow and black lines when tipping in the form, someone knows how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Check this post: https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` parameter to your scaffold to automatically move your contents up when you open your keyboard to prevent a bottom overflow.

```
Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
child: ...
);
```

alternatively you can wrap your from in a `SingleChildScrollView` widget to make any overflow scrollable.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(...),
);
```